# Vertica: Return zero if no records found

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I am running this query to get the average of logins per user for the last 3 months. If the user has logged-in in the last 3 months, get its average, if not return 0.

I have tried a number of different ways but seems like if the user has not logged in during the last 3 months, there are no records and the count() does not return 0. It simply returns nothing.

```
1) select case count(*)
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE count(creationTS) / 3
                END as average
              from table_name where creationTS >= add_months(now(), -3)
              and userId = '110'
             group by userId;

2) select COALESCE(count(creationTS)/3,0) as average
              from table_name where creationTS >= add_months(now(), -3)
              and userId = '110'
             group by userId;
```

It gives correct result if a record is found for the condition 'creationTS >= add_months(now(), -3)' but no record exists, it returns nothing. How can I return 0 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

a) get all distinct userid-s from the base table in a full-select.

b) left join that full-select back with the base table, on equality of the user id and login date not earlier than 3 months ago

c) count the found user id-s in the base table, getting NULL by default if the join fails, and use NVL() to force a 0 in case of NULL, and group by user id

```
WITH
-- sample input data,not part of real query
indata(userid,login_dt) AS (
            SELECT 'arthur',   DATE '2021-09-15'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'arthur',   DATE '2021-08-27'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'arthur',   DATE '2021-08-01'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'trillian', DATE '2021-09-27'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'trillian', DATE '2021-08-15'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'trillian', DATE '2021-06-27'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ford',     DATE '2021-02-27'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ford',     DATE '2021-04-27'
)
,
userids AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    userid
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  userids.userid
, NVL(COUNT(indata.userid),0) AS login_count
FROM userids
LEFT JOIN indata
 ON userids.userid=indata.userid
AND login_dt >= ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-3)
GROUP BY
  userids.userid
;
  userid  | login_count 
----------+-------------
 arthur   |           3
 ford     |           0
 trillian |           2
```